# Spark long running jobs with dataset

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have  a spark code that used to run batch jobs(each job span varies from few seconds to few minutes). Now I wanted to take this same code and run it long running. To do this I have thought to create spark context only once and then in a while loop  I would wait for new config/tasks to come and will start executing them.

So far whenever I tried to run this code, my applications stops running after 5-6 iterations without any exception or error printed. This long running job has been assigned with 1 executor with 10GB of memory and a spark driver with 4GB of memory(which was good for our batch job). So my questions is what are various things that we need to do to move from small batch jobs to long running jobs within code itself. I have seen this useful link - http://mkuthan.github.io/blog/2016/09/30/spark-streaming-on-yarn/ but this link is mostly about spark configurations to keep them running for long.

Spark version - 2.3 (can move to spark 2.4.1) running over yarn cluster

Comment: What could be the nature of new configs/tasks here. Is it a streaming data ? Looks like the application has to be re-written as a spark streaming job.

Comment: streaming should be considered if I have second or sub second query requirement. My simple requirement currently is to run same spark context every few minutes.